# Plotting in maple/MATLAB

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, maple

How do you plot the following parametric equation (equation of an ellipse) in the same graph

$$ x = a\cos{t} $$
$$ y = b\sin{t} $$

with varying value of $a$ and $b$ in either maple or MATLAB ?

Many thanks.

Comment: [MaplePrimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com/) is a better place for such questions.

Comment: Thanks .. Didn't know that !! ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in MATLAB:

```
min_a = 1; max_a = 10;
min_b = .5; max_b = 5;
t = linspace(0,2*pi,101);
cost = cos(t);
sint = sin(t);

N = 21; % Number of distinct values of a, b to plot
a = linspace(min_a,max_a,N);
b = linspace(min_b,max_b,N);

x = kron(a',cost);
y = kron(b',sint);

figure; hold on
for i=1:size(x,1)
    plot(x(i,:),y(:,:))
end
```

[image]

---

Code comparison for loop versus vectorization techniques:

```
clear all
clc
time = zeros(5,1);
for k=1:5
    close all
    tic
    min_a = 1; max_a = 10;
    min_b = .5; max_b = 5;
    t = linspace(0,2*pi,101);
    cost = cos(t);
    sint = sin(t);

    N = 21; % Number of distinct values of a, b to plot
    a = linspace(min_a,max_a,N);
    b = linspace(min_b,max_b,N);

    x = kron(a',cost);
    y = kron(b',sint);

    figure(1); hold on
    for i=1:size(x,1)
        plot(x(i,:),y(:,:))
    end
    time(k) = toc;
end
mean(time(2:end))

clear all
time = zeros(5,1);
for k=1:5
    close all
    tic
    min_a = 1; max_a = 10;
    min_b = .5; max_b = 5;
    t = linspace(0,2*pi,101);
    N = 21; % Number of distinct values of a, b to plot
    a = linspace(min_a,max_a,N);
    b = linspace(min_b,max_b,N);

    figure(1); hold on
    for i=1:length(a)
        for j=1:length(b)
            for l=1:length(t)
                x = a(i)*cos(t(l));
                y = b(j)*sin(t(l));
                plot(x,y)
            end
        end
    end

    time(k) = toc;
end
mean(time(2:end))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command and the plot

> plot([[ cos(t), 2*sin(t), t = 0 .. 2*Pi], [2*cos(t), 3*sin(t), t=0 .. 2*Pi],[4*cos(t), sin(t), t = 0 .. 2*Pi]], color = [blue, yellow] );

[image]

Comment: This method works but suppose if i want plot for `a=1..10` and `b=1..10`, this seems to be a very tedious task.

 
I know commands for explicit equations, eg  `plot({a*sin(t) $ a =-1..1},t=0..2*Pi)`  Maybe you can manipulate it and tell me the same for parametric equations. Meanwhile i'll also try MaplePrimes as user64494 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following codes in Maple 17 to do your job.

```
 > with(plots):
 > with(student):
 > for i to 80 do a[i] := i*cos(x) od:
 > for i to 80 do a[i] := \sqrt{i}*sin(x) od:
 > d := seq([a[i], b[i], x = -5 .. 5], i = 1 .. 80);
 > plot({d});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab

```
for a=1:3
   for b=1:3
      for t=0:0.01:2*pi
         x=a*cos(t);
         y=b*sin(t);
         hold on
         plot(x,y)
      end
   end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Never loop over t. `cos` and `sin` work just fine on vectors.

Comment: Right but takes too much space in memory

Comment: Ummmm.... what?

Comment: You're not saving any memory when you `hold on` and plot a set of single points. That still takes up memory, even when you over-write the variable, because MATLAB creates a separate data structure for the axes that completely contains all data used to generate the plot.

Comment: But in your case you have the plot + vectors

Comment: And? The memory overhead is comically small compared to the run time losses incurred by looping. MATLAB is explicitly designed to be optimized around matrix and vector operations. It's memory allocation and speed is far superior when used that way.

Comment: Since I usually use C++ you may be right. I can check the vm and cpu times and let you know. In usual case I prefer use less memory because vm and framing can cause loss of time and data.

Comment: I'm running two examples of the code, first using my method, second using yours, with the same number of parameters as in my code (so the same quantization of time, and the same domain for a and b). The workspace was cleared before each method, and each method was run 5 times. The first run was discarded, and the average of the next four runs was computed. The figure was cleared before each run.
$${}{}$$
Vector method avg runtime: 0.0568 sec
$${}{}$$
Loop method avg runtime: 15.4013 seconds.

Comment: That is a big difference. I will also try this, thanks.